# Blog posts on main frontpage

Tags: blog

I have a main company site and a blog subsite.  I want to display the posts & comments from the blog on the main homepage of the main site, along with some other content.

I have looked into Content Query web parts but I'm not sure what I'm doing or the best way to get started, could someone point me in the right direction???  Using Sharepoint 2010 Standard.

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you the overview of the process and hopefully kickstart something that will get a post with more detail:

You will need to add a CQWP to the page and configure it to pull posts.  Then you will need to export the webpart and modify the fields it is pulling in.  By default you only get the titles, you need to configure it to get the "rich html" field which is the body of the posts.  Re-upload the new webpart, add it to the page.  You can style it via XSLT.

You have to do this to modify any default query done by the CQWP that you want to modify.

I do not believe the post comments can be pulled along with this.

** Edit
Eric Swinson provides a walk thru of this exact scenario here:  http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html